# No data displayed in template from Django TemplateView

Tags: django, output

I am new to Djago and am trying to show the detail of an object from a list. Everything works from the code below except for the small matter of the detaill not being displayed.

Here is my view
`class PieceDetail(TemplateView):
template_name = 'cabinets/piece_detail.html'

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    id = kwargs.get('pk')
    piece = get_object_or_404(Piece, pk=id) 
    pprint(piece.pk)
    serializer = PieceSerializer(piece)
    pprint(serializer.data)
    return {'serializer': serializer, 'cabinets/piece_detail': piece.pk}
```

`Here is the url`path('piece_detail/int:pk/', views.PieceDetail.as_view(), name = 'piece_detail'),`

Here is the html

```
{% extends "shared/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}


</br>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
    <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
        <div class="btn-group me-2">
            <a href="/cabinet/piece_list" ><button class="btn btn-primary"> Back </button></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br class="modal-body py-0">
        <p>{{ serializer.data.id }}</p>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ piece.description }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ piece.quantity }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>The quantity shown is that usually used during construction of components</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

and here is some pprint output from the terminal on show detail selected
1
{'description': 'door rail', 'quantity': 2}
[03/Nov/2023 12:16:05] "GET /cabinet/piece_detail/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14603

I have tried various different methods to get the data from the view to the template, but it still seems to go missing.

If I use an APIVIew and add a request parameter to the get_context_data call, I get the message
`"detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."`

So I assume there is something major wrong in my function.

I am not sure how to get my serializer data to the template, but I expect I will be kicking myself when I find out what schoolboy error I've made

Answer (score 0):

For a template view, no serializer is necessary, nor recommended. You just pass the `Piece` object. In fact you don't need to use `get_context_data` either. This is all boilerplate code that can be handled by a [**`DetailView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview):

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView


class PieceDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'cabinets/piece_detail.html'
    # no get_context_data
```

then in the template, we render this with:

```
<br class="modal-body py-0">
    <p>{{ object.pk }}</p>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ object.description }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ object.quantity }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Willem, thank you. How remarkably simple compared to the rubbish I wrote.